# How to show all data before any filters applied in R Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, filter, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I want to show full data before any filter is selected and then subset the data as per the filter selection.

For example :
 - If nothing is selected then it should display all records
 - If only continent is selected and country and state filters are not selected then it should display all records of that particular continent
 - If Continent and Country is selected then it should display all records of the selected continent and selected country
 - If continent, country and state filters are selected then it should only display the records of those options of the selected filters

> Here is my code and link to the dataset
>   https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ii7fkt4anedjpb/R%20Codes.zip?dl=0

```
library(shinyjs)
library(stats)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sqldf)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(stats)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(sqldf)


setwd('C:\\Users\\folder')

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Shiny Dashboard")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data", tabName = "ShowData", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Summary", tabName = "ShowSummary", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ShowData",
            DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "ShowSummary",
            box(width =3,
                h3("Tutorial by TopBullets.com"),
                helpText("Please Continent, Country and State Combition"),
                uiOutput("continent"),
                uiOutput("country"),
                uiOutput("state")
            ),

            box(width =9,
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_subset")
            ))  ))

# Put them together into a dashboardPage
ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 15*1024^2)
server <- function(input,output){

  # Importing data and save it temporary in data variable
  data <- reactive({
    read.table(file = "C:\\Users\\folder\\Countries-Continents-csv.csv",
               sep = ",", header = T,
               stringsAsFactors = F)
  })

  # Showing the original data
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    DT::datatable(data(), options = list(scrollX = T))
  })

  # Creating filters
  output$continent <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "Continent", "Select Continent",choices = var_continent(), selected = "Asia")
  })
  output$country <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "Country", "Select Country",choices = var_country(), selected = "India")
  })
  output$state <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "State", "Select State",choices = var_state(),selected = "Goa")
  })

  # Cascasing filter for state

  var_continent <- reactive({
    file1 <- data()
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    as.list(unique(file1$Continent))
  })

  # Creating reactive function to subset data
  continent_function <- reactive({
    file1 <- data()
    continent <- input$Continent
    file2 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from file1 where Continent = '%s' ", continent))
    return (file2)

  })

  var_country <- reactive({
    file1 <- continent_function()
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    as.list(unique(file1$Country))

  })


  state_function <- reactive({
    file1 <- continent_function()
    country <- input$Country
    file2 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from file1 where Country = '%s' ", country))
    return (file2)

  })

  var_state <- reactive({
    file1 <- state_function()
    as.list(unique(file1$State))
  })

  output$table_subset <- DT::renderDataTable({
    file1 <- state_function()
    state <- input$State
    file2 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from file1 where State = '%s' ", state))
    DT::datatable(file2, options = list(scrollX = T))

  })

}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the summary tab, you can add an "All" entry to the top of each `selectInput` and filter only if the selected continent/country/state is not "All".  To do this for the the continent input, you would have:

```
as.list(c("All", unique(file1$Continent)))
```

Then the reactive function to get continent data would look like this:

```
continent_function <- reactive({
  file1 <- data()
  continent <- input$Continent
  sql = "select * from file1"
  if(continent != "All") {
    sql = paste(sql, sprintf("where Continent = '%s' ", continent))
  }
  file2 <- sqldf(sql)
  return (file2)
})
```

(And analogously for country and state.)